# How to create image slider using unity

Tags: unity, image, vuforia

I have created one unity app with vuforia plugin. App contains image target to view an object and play video. I need one more feature to create gallery view from image target.  I want to create something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhwhELJgdX4&feature=youtu.be&t=85 Please give me some instruction  how to make gallery view using vuforia. Please share any tutorial link or sample app with me.

Comment: Are you really just asking how to have two buttons which switch an image?

Comment: @Philipp thanks for quick reply. Yes I want to change image with arrow button .

Comment: @ jgallant  I am new and learning unity with vuforia. I just find virtual buttons but I have no Idea where to start for gallery view. Do you have any instruction link? If you have any tutorial then Please share with me.

Comment: This question is about how to get started, and is unfortunately off topic on this site.  What I suggest to you, is to provide as much information as possible to avoid getting your question closed.  Are you using Unity UI buttons?  Have you added an onClick event?  Have you loaded your images onto your scene in Gameobjects, or are you loading them via Resources?  

I could write a solution for you, but that is not the point of this site.

Comment: @jgallant, this question *is not* about how to get started. In fact, it starts with "I have created a Unity app", and does not follow suit for *any* of the alternate question s under the " getting started" close reason. It's  just very poorly researched.

Comment: Note that *comments* do not necessarily constitute *the question*.

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty simple stuff. You can use the following plugin. It's open source and there are video tutorial of how to use it. 
Download link: https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions
Tutorial linkL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJlIlWHlfMo